# overridden standard buttons not showing up at mobile and lightning experience action section

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout, button-overrides

We have overridden some standard buttons on several custom sObjects:

[image]

For some reason, they are not available as lightning actions to show them on record detail page:

[image]

[image]

Only the "delete" standard button is available, and that one has no override.
All these definitions are on a managed package, and the buttons don't show up on an org where the package is installed.
How do I enable the overridden buttons to add them as actions? From my understanding of the docs, I should be able to show these on my record page. Is there a configuration I'm missing?

Comment: Is this vf page part of managed package?  Also can you check override properties( https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_general_action_overrides.htm&type=5&release=212)

Comment: @Vinay hello, yes, the visualforce page is indeed part of the managed package. I checked the override properties, and it's all configured properly (default override from package is the correct visualforce, and the configuration on the org in question is to use the default configuration inherited from the package)

Comment: @Vinay maybe the "available for lightning experience and mobile app" configuration on the visualforce page? that option is not checked on the vf in question (on the manage package)

Comment: Yes you would need to have 'Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app' enabled on vf page.  Since page is part of managed package kindly reach out to package provider to make it enable.

Comment: @Vinay we are the package providers actually, so I had access and modified it. Please add what you wrote on an answer so if it actually solves this, I can point it as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have overridden standard buttons with VF page you would need 'Available for Lightning Experience, Experience Builder sites, and the mobile app' enabled on vf page so that 'Clone', 'Edit' are visible under 'Mobile & Lightning Actions' on page layout.

Thanks